# How to monitor data usage on a network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, monitoring, daisychaining

I'm on a ship with about 20 crew, our current setup is Starlink to a router then daisy chained wired routers(static ip,no DCHP) on 5 decks below. All routers are Dlink DIR 828a1 and can only see current data usage not total. We would like to be able to monitor and cap daily data usage by MAC address for the whole ship. How would we do that?

Comment: You can't with those routers. Most endpoints like phones/computers have tools for monitoring themselves or specific modes for metered networks, but for central monitoring, you'll need some fancier hardware. You'll want to track usage by IP, because a router may only see the MAC address of the next daisy-chained router (depending on how it's set up).

Comment: So could i replace the first router with a router or gigabyte switch and set the rest to access points and track IPs or MACs on first? Im open to replacing as needed i just need to know what to look for and how.